# How do I pass a value to a constructor and use it from a method in the same class?

Tags: java, class, graphics, icons

How can I pass a color variable to following class? I want to pass to the code variable in an RGB (-155) format:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.Icon;

public class ColorIcon implements Icon {
    ColorIcon(String iconColor) {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(Color.decode(iconColor)); //<-- This is the problem
        g.drawRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
        g.fillRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return 16;
    }
}
```

I need to use it in this way:

```
final static ColorIcon myMenuIcon = new ColorIcon("-155");
```

I get error "iconColor cannot be resolved to a variable" 
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store iconColor in instance variable

```
package com.epox.cmc.core.util;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.Icon;

public class ColorIcon implements Icon {
    String iconColor ;
    ColorIcon(String iconColor) {
        this.iconColor = iconColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(Color.decode(iconColor)); //<-- This is the problem
        g.drawRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
        g.fillRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return 16;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `iconColor` from your constructor into an [*instance variable*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), or [*field*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

```
public class ColorIcon implements Icon {
    private final String iconColor; // add an instance variable/field - see footnote †
    ColorIcon(String iconColor) {
        this.iconColor = iconColor; // set the field
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(Color.decode(this.iconColor)); // added "this" for clarity
        g.drawRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
        g.fillRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
    }
   /*the rest of your class*/
}
```

Instance variables allow you to store encapsulated "state" which you can read and write in methods that are called independently by external code. I suggest you read [The Java Tutorials > Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) to learn more about structuring classes.

However, in your class I'm not sure I would structure it like this. It may be better to attempt the `Color.decode` call inside the constructor, and store the field as the `Color` - that way the caller will be told immediately if there is a `NumberFormatException`, instead of at some later (arbitrary) point when `paintIcon` is called:

```
public class ColorIcon implements Icon {
    private final Color iconColor; // add an instance variable/field - see footnote †
    ColorIcon(String nm) {
        this.iconColor = Color.decode(nm); // set the field
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(this.iconColor); // added "this" for clarity
        g.drawRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
        g.fillRect(7, 5, 11, 11);
    }
   /*the rest of your class*/
}
```

<sup>†</sup> *As it seems that you will never change the instance variable `iconColor` I have also made it `final` to prevent accidental mutation at other points - you can remove this if you need to*